# Django comment form not submitting data [ERROR: function' object has no attribute 'objects]

Tags: python, django, forms, function, object

I have a comment form on a post page for submitting user comment. I keep getting this error:

```
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

The full trace-back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Steve Njuguna\Desktop\MoringaCore\Django-Instagram-Clone\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\Steve Njuguna\Desktop\MoringaCore\Django-Instagram-Clone\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Steve Njuguna\Desktop\MoringaCore\Django-Instagram-Clone\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Steve Njuguna\Desktop\MoringaCore\Django-Instagram-Clone\App\views.py", line 208, in AddComment
    comment_obj = Comment.objects.create(opinion = usercomment, author = user.id, post = post.id)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /post/1/comment
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Most answers on SO refer to identical model & function names but that is not my case. This is my model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    opinion = models.CharField(max_length=2200, verbose_name='Comment', null=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Comments'
```

My view

```
@login_required(login_url='Login')
def AddComment(request, id):
    post = Post.objects.filter(id=id)
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        usercomment = request.POST['comment']
        comment_obj = Comment.objects.create(opinion = usercomment, author = user.id, post = post.id)
        comment_obj.save()
        messages.success(request, '✅ Your Comment Was Created Successfully!')
        return redirect('Home')
    else:
        messages.error(request, "⚠️ Your Comment Wasn't Created!")
        return redirect('Home')
```

And my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'AddComment' post.id %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="d-flex flex-row add-comment-section mt-4 mb-4">
      <img class="img-fluid img-responsive rounded-circle mr-2" src="{{ user.profile.profile_image.url }}" width="38">
      <textarea class="form-control mr-3" rows="1" name="comment" placeholder="Your Comment" required></textarea>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Comment</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

And lastly my URL:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:id>/comment', views.AddComment, name="AddComment"),
]
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have a view that is named `Comment` as well...

Comment: Why do you search for `user` using `request.user` as a lookup for `username`, when `request.user` is already user object pulled from database?

Comment: Also provide full stacktrace of the exception or clarify the line of your code where this error occurs

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem nope i dont.

Comment: @sudden_appearance i have provided the full trace-back.

Comment: Please, try removing `user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)` and pass `request.user` directly to `comment_obj = Comment.objects.create(opinion = usercomment, author = request.user, post = post)`

Comment: @sudden_appearance i have done that. Now my new error is `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'` so i removed the `id` from `post.id` but then i get a new error `Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Post: John Wick>]>": "Comment.post" must be a "Post" instance.`

Comment: On the last one `filter()` is returning a list. use `Post.objects.get(id=id)` to fix that

Comment: @sudden_appearance thanks! Its works. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Delete `user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)` from your view, then change this:

```
comment_obj = Comment.objects.create(opinion = usercomment, author = user.id, post = post.id)
```

to this:

```
comment_obj = Comment.objects.create(opinion=usercomment, author=request.user, post=post)
```

Because you should not pass `id` where objects are seeked (in `ForeignKey` we need specific object, not its `id`).

Also change this:

```
post = Post.objects.filter(id=id)
```

To this:

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
```

Because you need specific object, not whole `QuerySet` of them.

Comment: i get a new error `Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Post: John Wick>]>": "Comment.post" must be a "Post" instance.`

Comment: I've edited. Check my answer again, please. You need switch from `filter` to `get`.

Comment: Nice work NixonSparrow... Nice work

Comment: @NixonSparrow thanks! Much appreciated.

Comment: @sudden_appearance I love when people like you give minuses just because I've posted an answer, and you found same issues and pasted in comments. I didn't have to ask anything because I've spotted all of it. Your behaviour is unprofessional.

Comment: @NixonSparrow you answer is now completely correct.

Comment: Sure. But good to know is that you can pass both `request.user.id` to `author` and `post.id` to `post` as django suits it for you)

Comment: That's true, but it is much better practise to pass whole object in classic situations and I believe it's better to pass such behaviour to beginners.

Answer (score 2):

So the initial problem with your question was in this line

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
```

I don't know how it even passed through Django Orm, but it intentionally did return something weird

You don't need to query for user object, because django queries user object to `request.user` by itself.

Also, `django.db.models.Model.objects.filter()` always returns QuerySet, which is not a Model object, it's a set of Model objects. When you are querying by primary key and you are sure that there is an instance with this id use

```
 django.db.Model.objects.get(pk=pk)  # Post.objects.get(id=id) in your case
```

> **Note:**. this method will reproduce ObjectDoesNotExist exception if there is no object found with this primary key, be aware of that.

Comment: Enjoy that 1 point bigger man :) Fine answer!